# Data validation on the result of a formula

Tags: validation, google-sheets

I'm looking for a way to default a cell value with data validation applied, but allow the user to overwrite the value to one of the valid values allowed.

I have a demo [spreadsheet here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i8OBRGvOO1LxmPWmKngIcBr9M_nViDrg-1wWktskByo/edit?usp=sharing).

And visually:

[image]

I have data validation on column D that provides a list of possible markup percentages from column G, however, I want a default value in there so I have written a formula to work this out (based on there being a value in an adjacent cost cell).

I enter the item, I enter a cost and the markup defaults. All good.

But, when I click the dropdown I don't get any values popup. the formula is shown instead.

I have tried conditional formatting based on making the cell text and background white, but this is sub-optimal for my real world (significantly more complex) scenario.

How can I achieve what I am after - a default value of 50% if there is a cost value, but selectable from the drop-down.

Comment: What's stopping you from putting 50% everywhere and adding data validation?

Comment: In my real sheet I have some other complexity that uses that field and it being blank. I also don't want to see it if there are no items associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to add a "default" value based on a condition is to use on edit (simple or installable) script.

Example:

The following is an simple on edit trigger. If a cell from column C below the first row is edited, then the cell to the right will be 50% (assuming that the cell format is set to display %)

```
function onEdit(e){
  if(e.range.columnStart === 3 && e.range.rowStart > 1){
   e.range.offset(0,1).setValue(0.5);
  }
}
```

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers